# Loading textarea with contents from file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**The Problem**

My goal is to be able to load text from a text document into the `<textarea>` to be displayed on the screen for the user. The $.get() call is able to retrieve the contents and seems to be storing them in the 'notes' global variable, but when .val() is called with 'notes' passed to it, it doesn't seem to be loading the string to be displayed within the `<textarea>`.

I have read through several previous questions on Stackoverflow and other articles on Google, but so far I haven't found any solutions. Does anyone have any suggestions?

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-md-5 module">
   <h1>My Notes</h1>
   <form>
      <textarea id="note-app" class="full-width full-height" placeholder="Save your notes here..."></textarea>
   </form>
</div>
```

**notes.js**

```
var notes = "pie";

$.get("../docs/notes.txt", function (data) {
    console.log('Loading notes...');
    notes = data;
});


function loadNotes(data) {
    console.log('Data:\n{\n'+data+'\n}\n');
    $("#note-app").val(data);
}

$( document ).ready(loadNotes(notes));
```

**Output**

```
notes.js:14
Data:
{
pie
}

jquery.min.js:4 XHR finished loading: GET
"http://localhost:63342/Dad/docs/notes.txt".k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @
jquery.min.js:4n.extend.ajax @ jquery.min.js:4n.(anonymous function) @
jquery.min.js:4(anonymous function) @ notes.js:7
notes.js:8 Loading notes...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just put the `$.get` inside of document-ready? It doesn't make sense to store this in a variable by the code you have shown. (If the only thing you want to achieve is that the content is fetched after document has been loaded)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $.get("../docs/notes.txt", function (data) {
        $("#note-app").val(data);
    });

));
```

or as a function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    function loadNotes() {
        $.get("../docs/notes.txt", function (data) {
            $("#note-app").val(data);
        });
   }

   loadNotes(); //Execute function now when DOM is loaded

));
```

**One other thing worth mentioning is that**

`var notes = "pie";` in your example is outside of document ready, therefore not accessible withing document-ready.

```
var notes = 'pie';
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert(notes); //will alert undefined or similar
    var notes = 'die';
    alert(notes); //will alert die
}
```

If you want a global variable like that you should use: window.notes = "pie";

```
var window.notes = 'pie';
$( document ).ready(function() {
    alert(notes); //will alert pie
    var notes = 'die';
    alert(notes); //will alert die
}
```

Comment: Fantastic suggestion. That is the way that I originally had it, but I ended up splitting everything apart hoping that it would lead to the discovery of the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A couple things...

`$( document ).ready(loadNotes(notes));` is invoking `loadNotes` immediately and not waiting for the document to be ready. You can pass a function by omitting the `()` - but you're simply invoking it.

Your `$.get` call has the potential to still be running when `loadNotes` gets triggered. Use a callback - wait for completion - then run `loadNotes`

Refactored:

```
function getNotes(callback) {
    $.get("../docs/notes.txt", function (data) {
        console.log('Loading notes...');
        callback(data);
    });
}

function loadNotes() {
    getNotes(function(notes) {
        $("#note-app").val(notes);
    });
}

$(document).ready(loadNotes);
```

Answer (score 2):

`$( document ).ready(loadNotes(notes));`

should be

`$( document ).ready(function() {
  loadNotes(notes)
});`

The [`ready()`](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) jQuery function takes in a function. What you're doing is executing the function right then, when that line of code is read. Not when the document is actually loaded.

Let me know if that fixes things for you.